# Parsing Date in string Database using getters/setters

Tags: java, android, listview, getter-setter

I'm trying to get a Date to Gmt+7 from listview Adapter :

```
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    _teamlist.clear();

    db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    db.getWritableDatabase();

    ArrayList<TeamModel> team_list = getTeams2();

    for (int i = 0; i < team_list.size(); i++) {


        String tdate = team_list.get(i).getTeamdate();


        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+7"));
        Date datex = null;
        try {
            datex = sdf.parse(tdate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        TeamModel _TeamModel = new TeamModel();

        _TeamModel.setTeamdate(datex);  ///// here the probleme !!!!!


        _teamlist.add(_TeamModel);
    }

}
```

in this line  '_TeamModel.setTeamdate(datex)' the error : "setTeamdate java.lang.String in TeamModel cannot be applied to java.util.Date "

My get/set class TeamModel:

```
public class TeamModel {

public String   teamdate="";
....

public String getTeamdate() {
    return teamdate;
}

public void setTeamdate(String teamdate) {
    this.teamdate = teamdate;
}
}
```

i tried to change teamdate in this class to date from string but it mess up my DBHelper

Comment: you're passing a String to a method that needs a Date... this just can't work. For your use case it seems to be useless to parse your date to String

Comment: @mithrop Is not the opposite? The OP is passing a Date to a method that needs a String. I could not understand what the OP was trying to achieve either way.

Comment: @tato.rodrigo I don't really know actually... he tells that he changed the `setTeamdate` to be able to pass a String... I'm thinking about a lake a OOP knowledge or something...

Comment: @mithrop im trying the opposite, i know this not working i need any suggest to solve this.

Comment: @MounirElfassi ok. still simple : you're passing a Date instance to a method waiting a String... parse your Date object to String.

Comment: @tato.rodrigo 100% this is my problem, how can i change for example my TeamModel to accept date instead of string

Comment: @mithrop how please?

Comment: guy, please... make some researches ! http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String, java.text.ParsePosition)

Comment: @mithrop thank you, your suggesting helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to "**mithrop**" for his help, this's what i did to fix the problem :

```
        String tname = team_list.get(i).getTeamname();
        String topponent = team_list.get(i).getTeamopponent();
        String tdate111 = team_list.get(i).getTeamdate();


        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+9"));
        Date datex = null;
        try {
            datex = sdf.parse(tdate111);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        String tdate = sdf.format(datex);

        System.out.println(tdate);


        TeamModel _TeamModel = new TeamModel();

        _TeamModel.setTeamname(tname);
        _TeamModel.setTeamopponent(topponent);
        _TeamModel.setTeamdate(tdate);

        _teamlist.add(_TeamModel);
```